# Laravel response()->download(), not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel

Why is this part of code is wrong ?  `foreach` loop in directory with-> file names and sizes and download link for each file.

When i ispect download button in chrome i got this in development tool:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-login text-uppercase mb-2" 
    download="HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    0: Content-Type: application/octet-stream
    Cache-Control:       public
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=testfile.pdf;
    Date:                Fri, 27 Nov 2020 13:58:31 GMT
    Last-Modified:       Fri, 27 Nov 2020 13:58:31 GMT
 ">Download</a>
```

when it the button i download file with name :

```
HTTP_1.0 200 OK_0_Content-Type_ application_octet-stream_Cache-Control_public_.pdf__Date_                
   Fri, 27 Nov 2020 13_58_31 GMT_Last-Modified_Fri, 27 Nov 2020 13_58_31 GMT__
```

insteed of `testfile.pdf`

`code`

```
   foreach($filesDownloadPath as $path) {

    $filesDownloads = pathinfo($path)['basename'];
    $filesDownloadSize = ConvertFileSize::ConversionFile(filesize($path));
    $downloadLink = response()->download(storage_path('app/Files/'.$filesDownloads), $filesDownloads, 
          $headers);
    }

    return view('page',["$filesDownloads" => 'fileDownloads',
                        "$filesDownloadSize" => 'filesDownloadSize',
                        "$downloadLink" => 'downloadLink'
    ]);
```

is problem with varibale `$downloadLink` ? with `response()->download()` ?

`blade`

```
@foreach($filesDownloadPath as $path) 
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $filesDownloads }}</td>
        <td>{{ $filesDownloadSize}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-login text-uppercase mb-2" download='{{ $downloadLink }}'>Download</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `response()->download()` does not make or return a "link", it is a response object (it is a response to return a file)

Comment: @lagbox do you know which right code assign to variable downloadLink to fix that?

Comment: i dont know your routes or what URL you want to use for that, but you need some URL to then send the browser to that route, and in that route you return the `response()->download(...)`

Comment: Where is your `$header` variable?

Comment: $headers = array( 'Content-Type: application/pdf', ); under foreach

Comment: I give an answer, it will work but make sure its `app/Files/` not `app/public`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response()->download()` produces a `Response` object which must be returned from a controller to do anything. You'll need to return an array of files names or ids to your template, e.g.,

```
$filesForDownload = [];
foreach($filesDownloadPath as $path) {
    $filesForDownload[] = [
        'path' => pathinfo($path)['basename'],
        'size' => ConvertFileSize::ConversionFile(filesize($path))
    ];
}

return view('page', ["filesForDownload" => $filesForDownload]);
```

then in your view:

```
@foreach($filesForDownload as $file) 
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $file['path'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $file['size'] }}</td>
        <td><a href="/file/{{$file['path']}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-login text-uppercase mb-2">Download</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Next we create a route in laravel pointing to a new method in your controller:

`Route::get('/file/{filePath}', 'YourController@downloadFile');`

and create a method in your controller which returns the `response()->download()`

```
public function downloadFile($filePath) {
    return response()->download(storage_path('app/Files/'.$filePath), $filePath);
}
```

Note that this basic code has absolutely no security checking and could allow any user to download any file within `app/Files` (or anywhere on your system depending on your PHP config). You can get around that by having a whitelist of files which can be downloaded or storing file info in a database and have them provide the file ID to download it.

Comment: i apply yout nice code, but i got this error in ````page.blade```` : ````Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\Finder\SplFileInfo as array```` this line -> ````<td>{{ $file['path'] }}</td>````

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. In the view `$filesDownloadPath` should be `$filesForDownload`

Comment: works! only need add one more````{}```` to ````<td><a href="/file/{$file['path']}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-login text-uppercase mb-2">Download</a></td>```` final tag: ````a href="/file/{{$file['path']}}````. Many thanks

Comment: Whoops, will edit the answer with those fixes!

Answer (score 0):

I download like this way

```
$file = storage_path()."app/Files/'.$filesDownloads";
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    ];
    return response()->download($file, "{$filesDownloads}", $headers);
}
```